# Preview image when item is clicked from a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, image

I'm creating a webpage in html that displays a list of cities on the left of the screen and when a user clicks on a city, an image is loaded on the right of the screen for users to see and when they click on another city that image is replaced with a new image matching the city clicked.

The aim is for users to see an image of each city they click on

[image: This is preview of what I'm aiming for]

I'm fairly new to this space and would appreciate the help.

Comment: "*would appreciate the help*" Help with *what*? Stack Overflow isn't a place you can have your code written *for* you; rather it's a place that you can get support on code you've already written. Edit your question to include your code as a [mre], along with a clear explanation of where you're getting stuck. See [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should add each of your images in a specific directory in your project, then add "id" attribute to **img** tag(" for example #image ")

```
onclick="showImage(this.id)"
```

add above line to each of your **li** tag and an specific id attribute (city name for exmaple).

then open a script tag above your  and paste these line :

```
   function showImage(id) {
buildimg = `./images/${id}.jpg`;
document.querySelector('#image').setAttribute('src', buildimg);
}
```

here I named the images folder "images" in root directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).